# is there any interpolation method in python which is similar to Empirical Bayesian Kriging?

Tags: python, interpolation, kriging, spatial-interpolation

EBK Regression Prediction is ESRI propriety tool for interpolation. But I am looking for some open source solution with same method Empirical Bayesian Kriging. I have 10 location rainfall data. I want to interpolate the data to fill the gap in between. my dependent variable will be rainfall data and explanatory variable will be DEM.

Comment: Yes, you can implement this method in Python. Was there a particular problem with it?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.